# Javascript, how to link array elements to different urls

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi this is the part of  my code.
 I need to link each image in the array to different urls.
Is this even possible to do it from inside, like
 `dataArrClothes.push(["imagename.jpg","<a href="someurl"></a> "Description"]);`
 Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var dataArrClothes = new Array();
dataArrClothes.push(["imagename.jpg", "Description"]);
dataArrClothes.push(["imagename.jpg", "Description"]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you want. Could you be more clear?

Comment: Can explain in more detail what you mean by "link an image to different urls"?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an array of objects instead of an array of arrays..

```
var dataArrClothes = [];

dataArrClothes.push({ img_src: "imagename.jpg", description: "Description"});

dataArrClothes.push({ img_src: "imagename.jpg", description: "Description"});
```

This would give you the following...

```
dataArrClothes[0].img_src; // "imagename.jpg"

dataArrClothes[0].description: // "Description"
```

You then have array of objects with `img_src` and `description` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object literal, such as:

```
dataArrClothes.push(
   {ImageUrl: 'imagename.jpg',
    Description: 'Your description here'
   });
```